# Percentages of wealthy and educated European immigrants to the US through out history?

Tags: united-states, immigration

I'm interested in knowing the percentages of wealthy and educated European immigrants to the US through out the country's history, but I can't find that online. I'll leave the definition of being wealthy and educated open because I'm more interested in the big picture, and I don't think it's reasonable to expect detailed information about it until 1950's right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to at least define your standard for educated.  Basic literacy, or Einstein and Fermi?

Comment: You are correct that its not reasonable to expect. The US didn't even really have **any** immigration laws [prior to 1875](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_Act_of_1875), so there would be no authority to collect those numbers, and no reason to want them. You'll probably be stuck with what can be gleaned from Census records.

Comment: Many of the earliest settlers of New England, who came during the "Great Migration", were well educated for the time, and of middling wealth; that is, they were merchants and land owners.  This can be confirmed by their written records.  The day of the "poor immigrant" is mostly during the latter 1800s.

Comment: @Peter Diehr: Though there were a number (Wikipedia says about half, prior to the Revolution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentured_servitude ) of poor immigrants who came as indentured servants, or as transported prisoners.

Comment: @jamesqf: That is why I said "Many".  I have ancestors from both categories from early Massachusetts - about half were indentured servants, and the other half were well enough off to become citizens of their towns.

Comment: What is the denominator of the fraction you're looking for? Are you looking for the percentage of all immigrants to the US (denominator = # immigrants to the US) who were wealthy and educated Europeans? The percentage of European immigrants to the US who were wealthy and educated? The percentage of wealthy and educated Europeans who immigrated to the US?